# How do you set encoding/fileEncoding option in readr/tidyverse?

Tags: r, encoding, tidyverse, readr

i have a textfile of an old spectrometer. It is encoded in "UTF-16LE" (I found this out with the `readr:guess_encoding()` function). I managed to read it in in base-r with:

```
spectra_gr2 <-  read.csv("~/some/path/spectra.csv", header = F, encoding = "UTF-16LE", fileEncoding = "UTF-16LE",  skipNul = T)
```

This works fine, but i want to do it using tidyverse/readr!
Does anyone know how i set the two options encoding/fileEncoding in `read_delim()` for Example?

Answer (score 9):

Use it in `locale`

```
readr::read_delim("~/some/path/spectra.csv", delim = ",",
       locale = readr::locale(encoding = "UTF-16LE"), col_names = FALSE)
```

Comment: If you don't have pkg:readr loaded there may not be a copy of `locale` available.